abp vnext, how to create user, then add default role?
role isDefault is set true
but not add when user is created.
so how?
create user, auto add isDefault role.
role isDefault What does it do?
check Volo\Abp\Identity\IdentityUserAppService.cs No role was automatically added.
How to achieve it? I missed it.
